# The same data is passed to the parent-component twice

Tags: angular, components

I am trying Angular and I got problem. I have a table, which contains an array of object (sensors). I change sensors by pushing them from the child-component to the parent-component and for some reason it seems to push the same data twice.
Here you can see how I create the array of sensors and the method to push to it.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sensors-table',
  templateUrl: './sensors-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sensors-table.component.css']
})
export class SensorsTableComponent{
  sensors: ISensor[] = sensors;

addSensor(sensor: ISensor){
  this.sensors.push(sensor)
}
...
```

Here a send this sensors to another component.

```
<app-add-sensor-modal
  [active]="addSensorModalActive"
  (onModal)="changeAddSensorModal($event)"
  (onSensors)="addSensor($event)"
></app-add-sensor-modal>
```

In this component i fill the form and add sensor to sensors.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-sensor-modal',
  templateUrl: './add-sensor-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-sensor-modal.component.css']
})
export class AddSensorModalComponent implements OnInit{
  @Output() onSensors = new EventEmitter<ISensor>()

addSensor(){
  let sensor: ISensor = {
    id: Math.random(),
    name: this.form.value.name,
    model: this.form.value.model,
    range_from: this.form.value.range_from,
    range_to: this.form.value.range_to,
    type: this.form.value.type,
    unit: this.form.value.unit,
    location: this.form.value.location,
    description: this.form.value.description
  }
  this.onSensors.emit(sensor)
  this.closeModal()
}
...
```

And as result I get 2 new sensors with identical attribute-values:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRIOh.png)

Comment: I suspect that `addSensor()` in `AddSensorModalComponent` is called twice for some reason. Yet you might have to show the HTML of AddSensorModalComponent, so that SO users have a chance to find the cause for your problem.

Comment: The part of your code you showed looks good. Its possible to create a Stackblitz repo?